# How can I restrict users to type only time range in a textbox with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Please how can I restrict users to enter only time range in a textbox using JavaScript so the textbox will look like(10:30 - 14:30). Thank you.

Comment: Can you just have two inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You can look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

You can limit the textbox by setting the type to `time`.
For instance, this should work: 
`<input type="time">`

If you want a time range in 1 textbox, you can limit it's input to this regex:

```
(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])\:(5[0-9]|4[0-9]|3[0-9]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|[0-9])-(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])\:(5[0-9]|4[0-9]|3[0-9]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|[0-9])
```

The final product would be:

```
<input type="text" pattern="(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])\:(5[0-9]|4[0-9]|3[0-9]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|[0-9])-(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])\:(5[0-9]|4[0-9]|3[0-9]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|[0-9])">
```

This requires the user to enter in (hh:mm-hh:mm)

The regex would be `(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])\s*\:\s*(5[0-9]|4[0-9]|3[0-9]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|[0-9])\s*-\s*(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])\s*\:\s*(5[0-9]|4[0-9]|3[0-9]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|[0-9])` if you want to account for whitespaces, such as `16 : 35 - 16: 45`

Comment: <input type="time" only give me one time and not a time range. Example, I want users to only type 09:20 - 13:30

Comment: Are you ok with having two textboxes, or do you want it to be in only one?

Comment: I want it to be only one textbox.

Comment: How can I validate the textbox with onkeypress using <input type="text" pattern="(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])\:(5[0-9]|4[0-9]|3[0-9]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|[0-9])-(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])\:(5[0-9]|4[0-9]|3[0-9]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|[0-9])">

Comment: The pattern validates it automatically.

Comment: Can I make the regex that you provided above to work like this ("return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==0 || ( event.charCode == 46 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)))")?
So that it will not allow alphabet and still maintain the pattern hh:mm-hh:mm

Answer (score 0):

You might want to grab the value of your `textarea`. Having the value will let you to run some operations on the string and test against some validation rules.
Here is sample code:

```
const textarea = document.getElementById("someId");
let cachedValue = textarea.value;
let lastValue = '';
textarea.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const currentValue = e.target.value;
  const first = currentValue.split('-')[0];
  const second = currentValue.split('-')[1];
  const isValid = currentValue.includes("-") && first.includes(":") && 
  second.includes(":") && currentValue.length <= cachedValue.length;
  if (isValid) lastValue = currentValue;
  if (!isValid) textarea.value = lastValue;
})
```

This assumes your `textarea` and it's value look like this:

```
<textarea id="someId" name="appt-time" value="13:30-23:30">13:30-23:30</textarea>
```